# Qt 4.8.4 Creating release

Tags: qt, release, qtserialport

I'm trying to build a release version of a project I'm working on. When building in Qt creator in Debug it works great. When I try building as release I get "cannot find -lQtSerialPort". Qt 4.8.4 does not include QtSerialPort. I had to add that manually. I'm assuming there is something I'm forgetting to include here. Possibly in the .pro file?

Also, I noticed in my Qt/4.8.4/lib directory I have many .prl files. There is one for QtSerialPortd.prl. This is the only one in here that seems to have a .dll version. Not sure if this is significant or not.

Makefile includes this:

```
Makefile: ???.pro
    c:/Qt/4.8.4/mkspecs/features/serialport.prf \

$(QMAKE) -config release -o Makefile ???.pro

c:/Qt/4.8.4/mkspecs/features/serialport.prf:
```

serialport.prf looks like this:

```
qtAddLibrary(QtSerialPort)

!isEmpty(QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_ROOT) {
    INCLUDEPATH -= $$QMAKE_INCDIR_QT/QtSerialPort
    QMAKE_INCDIR += $$QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_ROOT/include $$QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_ROOT/include/QtSerialPort

    QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_SUBDIR = src/serialport
    debug_and_release_target {
        CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
            QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_SUBDIR = $$QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_SUBDIR/debug
        } else {
            QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_SUBDIR = $$QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_SUBDIR/release
        }
    }

    QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_ROOT/$$QTSERIALPORT_BUILD_SUBDIR
}

mac {
    LIBS -= -framework QtSerialPort$${QT_LIBINFIX}

   if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
       LIBS += -lQtSerialPort$${QT_LIBINFIX}_debug
   } else {
       LIBS += -lQtSerialPort$${QT_LIBINFIX}
   }
}
```

Edit:

After figuring out I can change the name of the file by removing the d at the end, I realized that all the libraries included on the exe that is built include files that do not end in 'd.dll' with the exception of the QtSerialPortd.dll file.

I.E ldd on the debug .exe:

```
QtCored4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtCored4.dll (0x69cc0000)
QtGuid4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtGuid4.dll (0xf30000)
QtNetworkd4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtNetworkd4.dll (0x6cb40000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtSerialPortd.dll (0x63680000)
```

ldd on the release .exe:

```
QtCore4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtCore4.dll (0x6e0c0000)
QtGui4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtGui4.dll (0x67700000)
QtNetwork4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtNetwork4.dll (0x65c80000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtSerialPortd.dll (0x63680000)
```

Release vs Debug, it looks like the QtSerialPortd.dll remained the same. I'm guessing this is going to be problematic when I try this application on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of Qt/4.8.4/lib/libQtSerialPortd.a to Qt/4.8.4/lib/libQtSerialPort.a. It builds now. Not sure if this is going to have adverse effects.

Comment: You need a different library for debug and release builds. You can test for that using `config(release, debug|release)` and `config(debug, debug|release)` - for release and debug, respectively.